# Element 'Name' is already used with @org.simpleframework.xml.Element

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

The XML I need to parse has:

```
<Name>
    <Name>Fred</Name>
</Name>
```

I'm getting the error:

`Element 'Name' is already used with @org.simpleframework.xml.Element (etc)`

My code is:

```
@Root(name = "Name", strict = false)
public class NameData {

    @Element(name = "Name", required = false)
    private String name= "";
```

I understand why I'm getting this, but is there a way I can work around this?
Thanks

Comment: Doesn't your xml has namespaces?

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to show a minimal example to make it easier to read. Good question though.

Comment: If you have namespaces you can use them to access non unique element, namespace is designed to that purpose only.

Comment: If you provide your full xml I can help you out solving properly

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me:

```
@Root(strict = false)
@Path("Name")
@Text(required = false)
public class Name {
```

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXml can do it:

```
public class Name {
    @XmlName("Name")
    private String name;
}

final SimpleXml simple = new SimpleXml();
final Name n = simple.fromXml(xml, Name.class);
System.out.println(n.name);
```

Will print:

```
Fred
```

SimpleXml is in maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.codemonstur</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplexml</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```